# how to upgrade which python version jupyter notebook uses without multiple environments

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I just installed python version 3.10 I have set the path but Juypter Notebook is using version
3.8.11

Could you tell me how to set up my Jupyter notebook to run the  3.10 version?

I don't want to have multiple environments, just one.